# Reload page only once is not working on window version of safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, reload

I need to reload the page so that the product images that I'm selling on my shopify site can be changed to selected product option and it only seems to change the picture when the page is reloaded.
There should be other way to dynamically change the selected product image using more advanced javascript without refreshing the whole page but it's something I can't do by myself and I could not find someone who can do it for me.

So I have found code that reload the page only once when select function is triggered, which I thought this method is the easiest alternative solution for me.

The js code below is what I'm using at the moment,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.select').change(function() {
window.location.reload();
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The code will reload my page when product option is selected on the div below.

```
<div class="select">
<select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" name='id'>
{% for variant in product.variants %}
<option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
```

This code seems to work perfectly on Chrome, IE and Firefox browser, they only reload the page once and changes the product pictures for me but it constantly reloads the page on Windows desktop version of Safari browser.
I haven't tested on Safari on iphone or imac since I don't have them.
Any idea why it's not reloading only once but continuously reloads only on Safari browser?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The code below is using a `change` event on the `div`, and I have no idea how it's working in any browser, but it shouldn't work in none.

```
$('.select').change(function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Probably, if you change that to get the `select`, instead of the `div`, it will work:

```
$('.select > select').change(function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Although, if you show us the code of your image, for sure, we can find a better solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but your suggested answer did not solve the issue with safari. How do I add additional code here on comment?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed .ready to .click like below and it works fine on safari.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).click( function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```